# In what sense is an orbifold a DM stack?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks, algebraic-stacks, orbifolds

My advisor mentioned in passing that orbifolds are Deligne-Mumford stacks, and I'd like to know in which sense this is true. The only reference I can find is this article (https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.4160) by Lerman, which may answer this question but I'm in the process of working through it.

Comment: I also recommend https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0203100 (Orbifolds as Groupoids: an Introduction, by Ieke Moerdijk).

Comment: Kapranov and Vasserot's "the cohomological Hall algebra of a surface and factorization cohomology" is a nice introduction to analytic stacks. The point is that there is a map from the site of affine varieties over $\mathbf{C}$ to the site of Stein spaces.